# Discrete surface interpolation

Tags: matrices, interpolation, finite-element-method

I'm working on implementation of a **Fast surace interpolation using hierarchial basis functions** *(Szeliski et al)* algorithm.

The idea is: given a discrete function measurements of its values *(depths)*

$\{p_i\} = \{(u_i, v_i, d_i)\} = \{(u_i, v_i, \hat{f}(u_i, v_i))\}$

we are looking for such a function $f(u, v)$ so that it is very close to the original function, $\hat{f}(u, v)$ on its whole domain.

Note: we are dealing with discrete values. Thus, for convenience, let's denote a set of interpolated values as $\mathrm{x}$ and a set of measurement values as $\mathrm{d}$.

To do that, we try to minimize the *energy function*, $E(\mathrm{x}) = E_s(\mathrm{x}) + E_d(\mathrm{x}, \mathrm{d})$.

The *data cost* term, $E_d(\mathrm{x}, \mathrm{d})$, determines how close the interpolated surface *(or function)* is in reference to the original function.

The *smoothness* term, $E_s(\mathrm{x})$ encodes the curvature of the surface interpolated.

Now, the source problem is discretized using **finite element method**, which uses the **stiffness matrix**, $A$. To minimize the energy function, described above, the stiffness matrix is used too. It is said, to find matrix $A$ the authors solve this equation: $A\mathrm{x}=\mathrm{b}$ by setting:

$a_{(i, j), (k, l)} = \frac{\partial^2E(\mathrm{x}) }{\partial x_{i, j}\partial x_{k, l}} \Bigg|_{\mathrm{x}=0}$

and

$b_{i, j} = - \frac{\partial E(\mathrm{x}) }{\partial x_{i, j}} \Bigg|_{\mathrm{x}=0}$

**My question is**: why does the element of $A$ have those strange pair indices $a_{(i, j), (k, l)}$? Or maybe what is the stiffness matrix - is it 4-dimensional? Or what it looks like?

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For linear algebra purposes, you want to view the solution, forcing, etc. as vectors. For geometric purposes, you want to view them as matrices (because they are 2D). The usual compromise is to actually view it as a vector in code where you convert the 2D indices into 1D indices. There are two ways to do this (called column major and row major) but neither one is really preferred over the other. This conflict is reflected in our mathematical notation as well: we can keep indices as tuples of integers or we can write them as vectors of integers. Your source has chosen to do the former.

Comment: So the matrix $A$ would have dimensions $(n, n)$ given $n = ||\mathrm{x}||$ (the length of $\mathrm{x}$ vector)?

Comment: @shybovycha That's right (though $\| \|$ is weird notation for that notion of "length").

Comment: true, my mistake - should be one pipe: $|\mathrm{x}|$